# Не работает метод load

Tags: php, yii2, авторизация, framework

Всем привет!
Делаю регистрацию и авторизацию в yii2 и никак не могу понять почему не проходит валидация в модели формы.  В контроллере метод load() возвращает false.

Контроллер:

```
use Yii;
use app\models\auth\Login;

class UserController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    //Экшен по умолчанию
    public $defaultAction = 'login';


    public function beforeAction($action) {
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //FOR DEBUG
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }

    public function actionLogin()
    {


        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            //TODO
        }

        $model = new Login();
        //Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save())  {
            print('ok');
        }


        return $this->render('login');


    }

    public function actionRegister()
    {
        return $this->render('register');
    }

    public function actionPassword()
    {

    }

}
```

Модель формы:

```
namespace app\models\auth;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

class Login extends Model
{
    public $email;
    public $phone;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;
    public $typeLogin;
    private $_user = false;


    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['password'], 'required'],
            ['email', 'validateLogin'],
            ['phone', 'validateLogin'],
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
        ];
    }


    /*
    * Валидация введеного адреса эл. почты или телефона
    * @return bool
    */
    public function validateLogin($model, $attribute)
    {
        //TODO
        if ($this->email) {
            $this->typeLogin = 'email';
            return;
        }
        if ($this->phone) {
            $this->typeLogin = 'phone';
            return;
        }
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Неправильное имя пользователя или пароль!');
    }

    /*
    * Валидация пароля
    * @return bool
    */
    public function validatePassword($model, $attribute)
    {
        if ( !$this->hasErrors() ) {
            $user = $this->getUser();
            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Неправильное имя пользователя или пароль!');
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    * Авторизация пользователя
    * @return bool
    */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
        }
        return false;
    }


    /*
    * Поиск пользователя по логину или номкру телефона
    * @return bool
    */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            if ($this->typeLogin === 'email')
                $this->_user = User::findByEmail($this->email);
            else 
                $this->_user = User::findByPhone($this->phone);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }

    //public function load($data)
    //{
    //  $this->email = isset($data['email']) ? $data['email'] : null;
    //  $this->phone = isset($data['phone']) ? $data['phone'] : null;
    //  $this->password = isset($data['password']) ? $data['password'] : null;
    //  $this->rememberMe = isset($data['rememberMe']) ? $data['rememberMe'] : null;
    //  parent::load($data);
    //}

}
```

Модель идентификации:

```
<?php

namespace app\models\auth;

use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;

/**
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $phone
 * @property string $password
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $sename
 * @property string $fathername
 * @property integer $group_id
 * @property integer $enabled
 * @property string $last_ip
 * @property string $created
 * @property integer $subscribed_on_news
 * @property integer $downloaded_to_unisender
 */
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{


    private $salt = '79d6e182b3c811c559e6b';


    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 's_users';
    }


    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['email', 'phone', 'name', 'sename'], 'required'],
            [['group_id', 'enabled', 'subscribed_on_news', 'downloaded_to_unisender'], 'integer'],
            [['created'], 'safe'],
            [['email', 'password', 'name', 'fathername'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['phone', 'sename'], 'string', 'max' => 30],
            [['last_ip'], 'string', 'max' => 15],
            [['phone'], 'unique'],
        ];
    }


    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'phone' => 'Phone',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'sename' => 'Sename',
            'fathername' => 'Fathername',
            'group_id' => 'Group ID',
            'enabled' => 'Enabled',
            'last_ip' => 'Last Ip',
            'created' => 'Created',
            'subscribed_on_news' => 'Subscribed On News',
            'downloaded_to_unisender' => 'Downloaded To Unisender',
        ];
    }

    /*
    * Поведения
    */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::className()
        ];
    }

    /*
    * Поиск пользователя по email
    * @param string $email
    * @return 
    */
    public function findByEmail($email)
    {
        return static::findOne(['email' => $email ]);
    }

    /*
    * Поиск пользователя по номеру телефона
    * @param string $email
    * @return
    */
    public function findByPhone($phone)
    {
        return static::findOne(['phone' => $phone ]);
    }


    /*
    * Проверка пароля
    * @parem string $password
    * @return bool
    */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return $this->password === md5($this->salt.$password.md5($password));
    }

    /*
    *  Добавление/Изменение пароля
    */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = md5($this->salt.$password.md5($password));
    }

    /*
    * Генерация случайной строки для индетификации пользователя,
    * например может понадобится в опции "запомнить меня"
    */
    public function generateAuthKey()
    {
         $this->authKey === $app->security->generateRandomString();
    }


    /* Реализация методов интерфейса IdentityInterface */


    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne($id);
    }

    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
       //return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->authKey;
    }

    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если форма входа генерируется с помощью ActiveForm, то названия у полей будут в таком формате(примерно):

```
LoginForm[username] // LoginForm - название формы
LoginForm[password] // Аналогично
```

Если же у вас свой код html на форме входа, то в таком:

```
username
password
```

Метод load() также принимает имя формы. Можно указать пустое значение, тогда все будет работать.
Пример:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), '') && $model->save())  {
    print('ok');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В запросе должен быть Ваш массив с ключом Вашей формы.

```
 [LoginForm] => Array
    (
        [email] => mail@gmail.com
        [password] => 123456
    )
```

Если ключа LoginForm нет, тогда метод load вернет false